# RegEx To capture URL between angle brackets (or pipe)

Tags: javascript, regex

Consider the following URLs:

- `<http://www.google.com>`
- `<http://www.google.com|www.google.com>`
- `<http://google.com|google.com>`

I'm trying to figure a RegEx that would capture the URL after `<` up until `|` OR `>`

I've tried `URL.match(/<([^>|\|]+)/g)` but it always capture the first `<`

Desired output is simply: `http://www.google.com`

Comment: `url.split("<")[1].split(">")[0].split("|")[0]` :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The RegEx is correct. [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) will return the complete match set. You need to extract the first captured group.

Use [`RegExp#exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) to get the URLs.

```js
var str = `<http://www.google.com>
<http://www.google.com|www.google.com>
<http://google.com|google.com>`;

var regex = /<([^>|\|]+)/g;

var urls = [];
while(match = regex.exec(str)) {
    urls.push(match[1]); // Get first captured group, and push in array
}

console.log(urls);
document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(urls, 0, 4) + '</pre>';
```

---

You can also use [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) as follow:

```
str.match(/[^<>|\s]+/g)
```

```js
var str = `<http://www.google.com>
<http://www.google.com|www.google.com>
<http://google.com|google.com>`;
var urls = str.match(/[^<>|\s]+/g);

console.log(urls);
document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(urls, 0, 4) + '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 2):

This kind of pattern doesn't complex require regular expressions! You can use a **simple pattern** and **string operations**:

```
var url = "<http://www.google.com|www.google.com>";
var parts = url.replace(/^<|>$/, "").split("|");
```

---

For the solution using **regex**, try the following:

```
var url = "<http://www.google.com|www.google.com>";
var match = /(?:<|\|)([^>|]+)/g.exec(url);
```

You can then access the value of the first capturing group like this:

```
var url = match[1];
```

By calling `exec` on the same regular expression several times, you can find multiple matches (the multiple URLs you're looking for).

Explanation of the regular expression:

- `(?:<|\|)` is a non-capturing group (`(?:   ...   )`) that looks for either a `<` or a `|` symbol at the beginning. (In your case, every URL will either have a `<` or a `|` on the left side of it!)
- `([^>|]+)` is a capturing group (`(   ...   )`) that capturing a sequence of characters that are **not** `>` or `|`. You don't need to escape the `|` within a character class, it only has special meaning outside of it.

Comment: `url.replace(/^<|>$/, "").split("|");` **does** use a regular expression.

Comment: You're right, I've added "complex" to hit home the point I was making. ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
str.match(/(http\:.*)(?=\|)/)[0]
```

---

```js
var strs = ["<http://www.google.com>",
"<http://www.google.com|www.google.com>",
"<http://google.com|google.com>"];

strs.forEach(function(str) {
  // if `str` contains `|` character,
  // match characters that are followed by `|`
  if (/\|/.test(str)) {
    console.log(str.match(/(http\:.*)(?=\|)/)[0])
  } 
  // else match characters that are not `<`, `>`
  else {
    console.log(str.match(/[^<>]+/)[0])
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

[**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/k2jb60vg/)

```js
var url1 = '<http://www.google.com|www.example.com>',
  url2 = '<http://www.yahoo.com>';

console.log(url1.replace(/<|>/g, '').split('|'));
console.log(url2.replace(/<|>/g, '').split('|'));
```